# Appropriate objective for a data science project

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining

I've done a couple of DA projects found on the internet and I want to start one myself. I'm interested in baseball data and I think I can exploit a lot of that data but also want to delimit the topic. For example, predicting the winner of a season or something like that feels a bit over the top (as far as I have researched is very complicated work if I really want to pull a decent result).

So, hopefully, someone can throw me some suggestions for an objective using baseball data to start practicing :)